# How to run a query setting a dynamic spot date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I currently have to improve a query that actually brings information from the moment you run it to the past two years. This means if we run it today 24/05/2019 will bring information from 24/05/2017 to today.

But now I will need to change this to bring information from the current starting date of the year you run the query (01-01-201X) and considering the past two years (01-01-201X-2) this means that  it is supposed to be run today and will bring information from 01-01-2017 to 01-01-2019 and that should work based on the day you run the report. Any suggestion?

This is in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
SELECT     
    dbo.Customer.[No.], dbo.Customer Detail.[Posting Date], 
    dbo.Customer Detail.[Initial Entry Global Dim. 1], 
    dbo.Customer.Blocked
FROM
    dbo.Customer 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Customer Detail ON dbo.Customer.[No.] = dbo.Customer Detail.[Customer No.]
WHERE     
    (dbo.Customer Detail.[Posting Date] >= DATEADD(yy, - 2, CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE(), 102)))
```

Comment: `DATEADD(yy,`? Why not `DATEADD(YEAR`? Clearly you know why `y` doesn't work, but will the next person who reads your code?

Comment: Since @AaronBertrand won't plug his own blog, I will--because it's great. [Bad Habits to Kick: Using shorthand with date/time operations](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations). Get the full revived list [here](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-revival/)

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution in SQL Server is to use `DATEDIFF()`:

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(year, dbo.CustomerDetail.[Posting Date], getdate()) <= 2
```

And index-compatible solution uses `datefromparts()`:

```
WHERE dbo.CustomerDetail.[Posting Date] >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE() - 2, 1, 1)
```